# Something strange happens with parseInt()

Tags: javascript

So, I have the following issue:

```
let str = "M1"
console.log(parseInt(str.charAt(0)) != NaN))
```

It says `true` for some reason. Same with `1M`.
As long as I know, `NaN` is a `number` type.
Though, I need `(parseInt(str.charAt(0)) != NaN) == false` in this case. And `true` in case of `1M`.
Thanks for every answer.
PS* `parseInt(str)` returns `NaN`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than trying to prove a negative and prove that something is not NaN (remembering that NaN istelf means Not a Number) and expecting a false... too many double negtives

try simply `isNaN(str[0])`

```js
let str1 = "M1";
let str2 = "1M";

let result1 = isNaN(str1[0]);
let result2 = isNaN(str2[0]);

console.log(result1); // gives true - ie: str1[0] is not a number
console.log(result2); // gives false -ie: str2[0] a number
```

Answer (score 1):

`NaN === NaN` is false, so you can't just compare them with `===` or `!==`

You can use `isNaN(parseInt(str.charAt(0))` instead.

Answer (score 1):

You can't compare `NaN` with `==` operator. Easily check it in `if`:

```js
let str = "M1"

if(!parseInt(str.charAt(0)))
    console.log("NaN")
```

Answer (score 1):

It is working as expected. [NaN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NaN) is global property and is of not type number.

Here `parseInt('M1'.charAt(0)) != NaN` will be tested as `NaN !== NaN`. Since `NaN` is a global object these two `NaN` are not pointing same object but two different objects. So it is returning `true`

In second case `(parseInt('1M'.charAt(0)) !== NaN)`, it is obvious `true` as `1 !== NaN`.

Note: Use `===` instead of `==`

Answer (score 1):

Because: `NaN` is not equal to `NaN`

```js
let str = "M1"
console.log(parseInt(str.charAt(0)) != NaN))
```

`parseInt(str.charAt(0))` is a `NaN` value which is not equal to another `NaN` value.
Check this out [NaN - JavaScript | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NaN)